# json многомерного массива

Tags: php, json

У меня есть массив

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
    [0] => Array
                (
               [category_name] => Тест
               [spots] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [spot_id] => 1
                                [price] => 11000
                                [profit] => 10000
                                [visible] => 1
                            )

                    )

      )
    [2] => Array
                (
               [category_name] => Тест2
               [spots] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [spot_id] => 1
                                [price] => 11000
                                [profit] => 10000
                                [visible] => 1
                            )

                    )
      )
    [3] => Array
                (
               [category_name] => Тест3
               [spots] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [spot_id] => 1
                                [price] => 11000
                                [profit] => 10000
                                [visible] => 1
                            )

                    )
      )
```

Как я могу каждый массив обработать и вывести в `<div>category_name...</div>`
То есть 3 массива и на странице 3 div, если больше массивов соответственно больше div

Comment: С помощью цикла `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = [ 'response' =>
    array(
    ['category_name' => 'Тест'],
    ['category_name' => 'Тест2'],
    ['category_name' => 'Тест3']
    )
];

foreach ($array['response'] as $value) {
    echo '<div>' . $value['category_name'] . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
    [0] => Array
                (
               [category_name] => Тест
      )
(
[spots] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [spot_id] => 1
                                    [price] => 11000
                                    [profit] => 10000
                                    [visible] => 1
                                )

                        )

А если у меня в массиве есть еще один массив как тогда вытащить?

Comment: @RuslanKrasulia пример такой-же что и в вопросе, а тот что в вопросе - я на него дал ответ.

Comment: Отредактировал код в вопросе

Comment: @RuslanKrasulia ну в моем примере достаточно обращаться к полям так: `$value['spots'][0]['spot_id']`, можно внутри `foreach` сделать перебор по `sports` (если нужно), но думаю уже справитесь

Comment: Затупил, все понял

Comment: Такой еще вопрос, а если у меня есть  [ingredients] => Array и внутри много массивов [0], [1], [3], [4] [...] как я их могу обработать?

Comment: @RuslanKrasulia перебор массивов это `foreach` - http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

> Как я могу каждый массив обработать и вывести в `<div>category_name...</div>` То есть 3 массива и на странице 3 div, если больше массивов соответственно больше div

Вот такой пример обработки:

```
$ar = [ 'response' =>
    array(
    ['category_name' => 'Тест'],
    ['category_name' => 'Тест2'],
    ['category_name' => 'Тест3']
    ),

    'spots' => [ ['spot_id'=> 1], ['price'=>1000], ['visible'=> 1] ]
];

function printer($item, $key){
    echo "<div data-info='$key'>" . $item . "</div>" . PHP_EOL;
}

// Рекурсивный проход по всему массиву
array_walk_recursive($ar, 'printer');
```

Результат:

```
<div data-info='category_name'>Тест</div>
<div data-info='category_name'>Тест2</div>
<div data-info='category_name'>Тест3</div>
<div data-info='spot_id'>1</div>
<div data-info='price'>1000</div>
<div data-info='visible'>1</div>
```

Comment: А как мне тогда использовать определенную строку?

Comment: @RuslanKrasulia вам печатать или использовать?

Comment: Использовать только некоторые параметры

Comment: @RuslanKrasulia некоторые наугад или что-то конкретное?

Comment: Допустим category_name и price